# How to make divs and div children with inset border are perfectly touching left and top vertically descending

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table, but I do not wish to use a table.
I have instead placed divs inside other divs just as shown below:

```
<div class="windows" id="head">
    <div class="windows" id="location">
        <div class="windows" id="character">
            <div class="windows" id="buttons">
                <div class="windows" id="textbox"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="windows" id="map"></div>
</div>
```

And I want to have them essentially look just like this:
[Click image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uganP.png)

But as soon as I make the border in CSS for all divs to be :
border: 0px gold;

Then it lines them up with a 3px margin or padding:
[Click image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xGkq.png)

I've personally tried to set the margin and padding of *, body, #head, div and .windows to:

```
div {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

This has been fruitless.

A big chunk of the CSS currently looks like this, where the remaining divs go by the same pattern as #location. Where the "top" is always the "height" of the previous .

```
html {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: gabriela;
    text-color: black;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.windows {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block; 
    position: relative;
    border: 3px gold;
    border-style: inset;
    background-color: maroon;
}

#head {
    width: max(500px, 100%);
    height: max(150px, 15%);
}

#location {
    background-color: purple;
    width: 380px;
    top: max(150px, 15%);
    height: max(100px, 10%);
}
```

Comment: To be honest your code looks weird and over-complicated? Why are the elements inside each other? Why give them the golden border? Why are you using `position: relative` like that? It seems you only need five elements after each other, each with a different background color and a width (or maybe a grid layout, depending on what the black area is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are too over complicating, try using grid-layout it will be much easier.
Here is a link of how to use grid-layout https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp.